# Access instance passed when destructuring

Tags: typescript

I am discovering the destructuring feature in TypeScript and it seems like a timesaver. However I wonder how I can refer to the instance passed to a function when destructuring is used. Example below:

```
function fn({foo, bar}) {
    // access the A instance passed to function?
}
class A {
    constructor(public foo: number, public bar: number) {};
}
fn(new A(1,9));
```

Do I really have to look the arguments list or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the destructuring inside the method and not as a parameter and enjoy the both worlds

```
function fn(a: A){
 var {foo, bar} = a;
}

class A{
    foo:number;
    bar:number;
}

fn(new A());
```

Look [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20fn(a%3A%20A)%7B%0D%0A%20var%20%7Bfoo%2C%20bar%7D%20%3D%20a%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%7B%0D%0A%09foo%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%09bar%3Anumber%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afn(new%20A())%3B) for what it transpiles to, so you can have an idea of how it works and that it is not magic.
Here is a [documentation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html) for the Typescript Destructuring

Comment: Well, the idea was to avoid a.foo - I don't see how this solution utilizes destructuring?

Comment: My issue with this is that it doesn't allow default parameter values. Anyone know of a way to have both?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should simply use destructing one step later?

```
function fn(a: A) 
{
    let {foo, bar} = a;
    //You have both destruted foo, bar and original a
}
```